# Open two files pairwise out of many - python

Tags: python, list, compare

Hey guys I'm a rookie in python and need some help.

My problem is, that I have a folder full of text files (with lists in it), where two belong to each other and need to be read and compared.

Folder with many files:   File1_in.xlo, File1_out.xlo, File2_in.xlo, File2_out.xlo, ...

--> so File1_in.xlo and File1_out.xlo belong together and need to be compared.

I already can append the lists of the 'in-Files' (or 'out-Files') and then compare them, but since there are many Files the lists become really long (thousands and thousands of entries), so the idea is to compare the files or respectively the lists pairwise.

My first try looks like:

```
import os

for filename in sorted(os.listdir('path')):
    if filename.endswith('in.xlo'):
        with open(os.path.join('path', filename)) as inn:
            lines = inn.readlines()
            for x in lines:
                temperatureIn = x.split()[4] 

    if filename.endswith('out.xlo'):
        with open(os.path.join('path', filename)) as outt:
            lines = outt.readlines()
            for x in lines:
                temperatureOut = x.split()[4]   #4. column in list
```

So the problem is, as you can see, the 'temperatureIn's are always overwritten before I can compare them with the 'temperatureOut's. I think/ hope there must be a way to open both files at once to compare the list entries.

I hope you can understand my problem and someone can help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip` to access in-Files and out-Files in pairs

```
files = sorted(os.listdir('path'))
in_files = [fname for fname in files if fname.endswith('in.xlo')]
out_files = [fname for fname in files if fname.endswith('out.xlo')]
for in_file, out_file in zip(in_files, out_files):
    with open(os.path.join('path', in_file)) as inn, open(os.path.join('path', out_file)) as outt:
        # Do whatever you want
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, it helped a lot in combination with the answer of @Matina G (don't know if this works^^)

Comment: but can you explain, what happens here: fname for fname in files

Answer (score 0):

add them to a list created just before your for loop, as:

```
 temps_in =[]     
 for x in lines:
     temperatureIn = x.split()[4] 
     temps_in.append(temperatureIn)
```

Do the same thoing for temperatures out, then compare your two lists

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, it helped a lot in combination with the answer of Sunitha.